# The meaning of "workload allocation"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> I am not sure that I would receive any workload allocation for this.

I heard a university professor said the above to someone. What that means? I searched on the Internet and I got the idea that it means something like "salary". 
Does it?

Answer (score -1):

It's [*jargon*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/jargon) used by the particular institution where this professor works.  We can guess the meaning is something like *"authorization to work on something"* or possibly *"funding"*, but we wouldn't know for sure unless we also worked at the same place, or another related institution in the same region.

Which is to say, it could be a term used informally among the staff and administration of that institution, or it could be a defined term in their employment contract, wherein the professor can only work on projects for which he or she has received an *allocation*.